# iTunes requires manual intervention to delete files when updating apps

Tags: windows-7, itunes, sync

When attempting to update apps in itunes i always get the following popup for every single app that gets updated. I've tried running itunes as administrator but doesn't help.
is it possible for me to simply click "update all apps" walk away and expect to come back sometime later with everything all done?

thanks in advance.

- win7 x64
- itunes 10.0.0.68

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your iTunes library on a mounted volume?  Seems like you're running into the problem where the Recycle Bin doesn't recognize mounted volumes and thus can't be used.  Typically this isn't a problem so much in explorer where you can shift-click to remove files and avoid the annoying message, or use `rd /s /q` at the command line, but in apps that try to use the Recycle Bin it's considerably more annoying.

In XP there was an option to skip the recycle bin - I do not know if this also exists in Windows 7.  Try right clicking on the Recycle Bin in explorer and choosing "Properties" - there may be a checkbox that says something along the lines of "Do not move files to the Recycle Bin.  Remove files immediately when deleted." - try using that if it's available.

Comment: yes you are right. this is exactly the issue. i totally forgot that i had made my itunes library on a mounted volume. now i just need to search a solution for recycle bin and mounted volumes issue.